# Counter values reset

Tags: drools, jboss6.x, drools-fusion

When I restart jboss server all Drools counter values have been reset. But I need to keep previous values after restart the server. How Can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "counters"? This isn't a term from the Drools Expert or Fusion manual.

Comment: Thanks Laune, I mean when i use drools variables, after restart the server all variables will reset. I just need to know what is the best practice for retain variable values after application server restart.

Comment: In simple terms I need to know how to prevent drools variable value change/reset after jboss server restart. Need to get already set variable after Jboss application server restart.